# jquery get instance of parents class

Tags: jquery, indexing, modal-dialog

I'm dynamically adding links to a page each link launches the modal.

I need to find which instance of the link launched the modal to display the right info.

so i have

```
<div class='linkHolder'><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'  class='modalLink'>View</a>"
```

I'm trying to find which link it is on the page by getting the occurance of the class linkHolder.

with this:

```
   function testindex()
{
    var test = ($(this).parent('.linkHolder').index());
    alert(test);
}
```

clicking the link launches this alert but its always -1 / not found

thanks

Comment: Is this a typo or do you close your div - it looks as if you are finishing whatever is printing the html before closing the div (because of the double quotes at the end of the line) - that may be your problem

Comment: sorry that's just because i have copied it from a string and the quote at the end is closing it. It is rendered closing correctly on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are adding these links dynamically, I would attach the click event using an `on` in your document load as such:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.modalLink', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent('.linkHolder').index());
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3CTNQ/3/)

The problem with your function is that you have not passed `this` into it so it doesn't know what `$(this)` is

**EDIT**

As per your comment, if you are just looking for the index where the `linkHolder` can be in any div try this:

```
$('.linkHolder').index($(this).parent('.linkHolder'));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/yAR73/1/)

Comment: Thanks, my page structure is more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yAR73/

so I need to know what instance it is anywhere on the page

Answer (score 0):

Try:

jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var myIndex = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;  
    alert(myIndex);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myClass"><button type="button">Click me</button></div>
<div class="myClass"><button type="button">Click me</button></div>
<div class="myClass"><button type="button">Click me</button></div>
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JgByw/)**

Comment: Thanks, will this only work if they are all within the same parent div?

Comment: Hi, no problem. What my codes does is it goes up a level from the clicked element and collects the sibling elements. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: They wont necessarily be siblings but they will be within div with class linkHolder

so there might be 10 div.linkHolder anywhere on the page each with 1 a.modalLink

Comment: oh then it's easy - move up to the container div with `.parent().parent()` etc. and then just do a `.find('.linkHolder')` and it will return all items with this class.